# Prove that any open interval $(a, b)$ that intersects $\bf C$ contains some subinterval of some $F_m$.

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

Prove that any open interval $(a, b)$ that intersects **C** (Cantor's set) contains some
subinterval of some $F_m$. Then conclude that $(a, b)$ also intersects the complement
from **C**.

My try:

In other words what the first part is asking me to prove is:

If $(a,b)\cap$ **C** $\neq \emptyset \Rightarrow$ $[\frac{n}{3^m}, \frac{n+1}{3^m}] \subseteq (a,b)$ for some $n, m\in \mathbb{N}$

Let $\xi\in [\frac{n}{3^m}, \frac{n+1}{3^m}]$ ...

I don't know if it's the right way to go. Any hints would be great!

Comment: What is $F_m$? What is your definition/construction of the Cantor set?

Comment: $F_m:=$ the union of $2^m$ close intervals of length $\frac{1}{3^m}$

Comment: Hint: Since the intersection with cantor set is non empty pick a common point, then by the openness you can find a neighborhood $I$ of that point. Finally choose a large $m$ so that your $F_m$ falls inside $I.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(a,b)\cap\mathbf C\neq\emptyset$, you can take some $c\in(a,b)\cap\mathbf C$. Take $m\in\mathbb Z_+$ so large that $a<c-3^{-m}$ and that $c+3^{-m}<b$. Now, take some $n$ such that $c\in\bigl[n3^{-m},(n+1)3^{-m}\bigr]$. Since the length of this interval is $3^{-m}$, it follows from the choice of $m$ that $\bigl[n3^{-m},(n+1)3^{-m}\bigr]\subset[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks! How would you coclude that $(a, b)\cap$C$^c\neq \emptyset$ ?